# How to hide SSID of Wi-Fi from the list of access point

Tags: macos

I'd like to know how to hide SSID from the list of Wi-Fi access point at the top menu of desktop. or I would like to keep my SSID only in the list.

Reason:

I need to take a video of operation on my desktop but I don't want to show other SSID which will be shown you where I'm.

[image]

Comment: Is your question related to wifi, or video editing?

Comment: I mean GUI on desktop

Comment: So you're going to be creating a video of steps and you'll want to "mask" (hide) the wireless networks you're connected to /nearby? You'll be easier to record the video as you intend and then find some free editing software that will allow you to blur the things you don't want people watching the video to see.

Comment: That's correct. But I would like to hide the name of SSID from the list which I mentioned as my question.